# Time to origin of the double integrator as a function of the initial state

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, optimal-control

I am working through some questions to prepare for an exam and was just hoping someone could assist me in checking if my approach is sound for this problem.

> Solve the problem of time optimal control to the origin for
>   $$\begin{array}{rl} \dot{x_1} &= x_2\\ \dot{x_2} &= u\end{array}$$ where $| u (t) |\le 1 $. If $x(0)=(a,b)$ lies above the switching curve, then find the time taken to reach the origin, $t_1$, as a function of $(a,b)$.

#### My approach

I'm fairly comfortable with deriving the optimal solution. So after applying the PMP and using the costate equations of the Hamiltonian, we arrive at the following:

$$
x(t)=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{ut^2}{2}+\beta t+\gamma\\
    ut+\beta
\end{bmatrix}
\\\
\\x_2^2=2ux_1+\alpha 
$$

Where, $u=\pm1$ and can switch at most once.

We have two families of curves, a $C_+$ family of quadratics opening towards the positive $x_1$ axis with $x_2$ increasing in $t$ and a $C_-$ family of quadratics opening to the negative $x_1$ axis with $x_2$ decreasing in $t$.

Each only has one curve through the origin, so we end up with the following 
[image: optimal system]

If above the paths through the origin, set $u=-1$ and follow a blue $C_-$path down to the origin seeking path before switching to $u=1$, and vice versa for points below.

### Now, the challenging part.

If we start above the switching curve at $(a,b)$, our $C_-$ curve can be written as
$$
\\x_2^2=-2x_1 + 2a + b^2
$$

And our switching curve is given by
$$
\\x_2^2=2x_1
$$

So we will switch at their intercept at 
$$
(\frac{2a+b^2}{4},-\sqrt{\frac{2a+b^2}{2}})
$$
Now we need to switch to parametric curves for the time.

If we set $t=0$ at $(a,b)$, our $C_-$ curve should be given by:

$$
\\x(t)=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{-t^2}{2}+bt+a\\
    -t+b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Subbing in the intercept point gives 
$$
T_1 = b + \sqrt{\frac{2a+b^2}{2}}
$$

If we do a similar approach on a $C_+$ curve starting at time $0$ at the switch point, we get
$$
\\x(t)=
\begin{bmatrix} 
    \frac{t^2}{2}-t\sqrt{\frac{2a+b^2}{2}}+\frac{2a+b^2}{4}\\
    t-\sqrt{\frac{2a+b^2}{2}}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Subbing in the origin and solving for time

$$
T_2 = \sqrt{\frac{2a+b^2}{2}}
$$

So the total time to origin is just
$$
T = T_1 + T_2 =  b + 2\sqrt{\frac{2a+b^2}{2}}
$$

Would be greatly appreciated if someone would be able to confirm if my approach is sound and correct. I feel like that, if this is the solution, there must be a simpler approach that I am missing, so if anyone could point me towards a more timely approach, that would be amazing.

Comment: The total time to origin appears to be correct. Take a look at pages 9 and 10 of [the rocket car](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~loew/m403/rocketcar.pdf).